# Javascript function inside Promise.prototype.then not executing

Tags: javascript, oop, methods, promise, prototype

I am using the Javascript promise api but my function inside then not executing;

```
//defining a class Test
var Test=function(){
    var x="hello from x";
}

//Adding a method with Test class
Test.prototype.someFn=function(){
   console.log("This is from somefn");
}

//Adding another function    
Test.prototype.anotherFn=function(){
   var self=this;
   var p=new Promise(
      function(){
         self.someFn();
   })

   p.then(
       function(){
            console.log("From anotherfn p.then");
   })
 }
```

And finally calling it in following way;

```
var t=new Test();
t.anotherFn();
```

The output is like;

```
This is from somefn
```

Why the "From anotherfn p.then" is not being printed. Any suggestion please.

Comment: Did you look at the documentation of the Promise constructor ?

Comment: The promise never gets fulfilled, since you don't show where you trigger `p.resolve( valueToResolveWith );` So your then function will never run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You never resolve the promise.

Change

```
var p=new Promise(
  function(){
     self.someFn();
})
```

to

```
var p = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
     self.someFn();
     resolve();
});
```

See [*Creating a Promise* in the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#Creating_a_Promise)

Note that you shouldn't wrap a synchronous function inside a promise. Assuming that `someFn` would be asynchronous, then the promise should be returned a that point.

Comment: Ok, now I got the catch. Thanks.

Comment: Yes actually I gave this example. But in real case I am calling an ajax inside promise.

Comment: Then be careful to resolve (or reject) the promise in the callback you give to the ajax function, not after the call to the ajax function.

Comment: @KOUSIKMANDAL yes, from inside these callbacks (depending in fact of the ajax API you're using)

Comment: Yes, I told you thinking about jQuery ajax. :)

Comment: jQuery's Ajax functions now return A+ promises, you don't have to create them yourself